# Erro ao dar o comando npm install

Tags: aplicação-web, npm

```
jean@jnotepc:/var/www/html/app_agenda/_views/css$: npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open     '/var/www/html/app_agenda/_views/css/package.json'
npm WARN css No description
npm WARN css No repository field.
npm WARN css No README data
npm WARN css No license field.
```

O que Devo fazer?

Comment: Acho que estás a correr o mpm install numa subdiretoria da app, e não na root da app...

Answer (score 1):

A pasta atual não possui um arquivo denominado `package.json`. Provavelmente você está na pasta errada. Acredito que a pasta correta seja `app_agenda`. Tente:

```
cd ../..
```

e depois:

```
npm install
```

Comment: Acredito que seja isso mesmo

Answer (score 0):

> /var/www/html/app_agenda/_views/css$: npm install

Você não esta na pasta certa, tente executar o comando na pasta onde exista o arquivo `packages.json`